# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse on any width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my problem is that my navbar is always collapsed and I don't know why... 
I have tried every thing but nothing worked.
hope you can help me. 
I have uploaded only the custom css and the html.The rest is bootstrap

```css
/* general styles */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* padded section */
.pad-section {
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    padding-top: 70px;
}
.pad-section img {
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand{
    color: whitesmoke;
}
.navbar-fixed-top{
    background-color: #34495e;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color:#e98b39;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav > li > a{
    color: whitesmoke;
}
.btn-default{
    background-color: rgba(236, 240, 241,0.5);
    color: #34495e;

}
.btn-default:hover{
    background-color: rgba(236, 240, 241,1.0);
    color: #e98b39;

}
.hr{
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

/* vertical-centered text */
.text-vcenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text-vcenter h1 {
    font-size: 4.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* additional sections */
#home {
    background: url(../Img/IMG_1999.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#about {
}

#services {
    background-color: #e98b39;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#portfolio{
    color: #34495e;
    width: 100%;
}
.portfolio-list > li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
}
.portfolio-button{
    background-color: #34495e;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
.portfolio-button:hover{
    background-color: #34495e;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #e98b39;
}

#information {
    background: url(../Img/_MG_0410.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    display: table;
    color: whitesmoke;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#information .panel {
    opacity: 0.85;
}

#contact {
    height: 500px;

}

.form-horizontal{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    max-width: 60%;
}

.submit-button{
    margin-top: 10px; ;
    background-color:#e98b39;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color:  #34495e;
}
.submit-button:hover{
    margin-top: 10px; ;
    background-color:#e98b39;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: white;
}
footer {
    padding: 20px 0;
}
footer .glyphicon {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 60px;
}
footer .glyphicon:hover {
    color: #306d9f;
}
.offset-0 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.container container-portfolio{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.pad-section .portfolio{
    padding-bottom: 0px ;
}
.navbar-nav > li{
    padding: 8px;
    float: left;
}
.navbar-right social{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="Matthias Skopek" content="Skopek-Art Portfolio" />
    <title>Skopek-Art</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll">
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header ">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">SKOPEKART</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#home" >Home</a></li>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#about" >Über Mich</a></li>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#services" >Fähigkeiten</a></li>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#portfolio" >Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#contact" >Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Matthias-S-Photography-1435230113356609/?ref=hl"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/matthias_skopek/"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://500px.com/matthiasskopek"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-500px"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        </div>
</nav>
<section id="home" class="home">
    <div class="text-vcenter">
        <h1>Hallo Welt</h1>
        <h2>Mein Name ist Matthias Skopek und ich bin 18 Jahre und begeisterter Fotograf, Grafiker und Web-Designer.<br>
            Ich besuche gerade die HTL Leonding im Bereich Medientechnik</h2>
        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Wollen Sie mehr erfahren?</a>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="about" class="pad-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="Img/pf-pic.jpg" alt="" style="max-width: 300px;max-height: 500px;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                <h2>Hallo mein Name ist Matthias Skopek ich bin 18 Jahre und begeisterter Fotograf, Grafiker und Web-Designer.</h2>
                <p class="lead">
                    Ich wohne in Leonding und besuche die HTL Leonding im Bereich Medientechnik im 3. Jahr.
                    Ich war schon immer kreativ und deswegen begeistert mich auch das Fotografieren und Design.
                    Ich arbeite gerne mit Menschen zusammen und das gefällt mir in meinem Bereich auch sehr gut.
                    Da man sich auf das Team verlassen können muss.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="services" class="pad-section">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center">Meine Fähigkeiten</h2> <hr />
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-5x"></i>
                <h4>Web-Design</h4>
                <p>Ich lerne Web-Design seit mittlerweile 3 Jahren in der Schule und ich habe auch schon einpaar kleiner Projekte für Firmen von Bekannten gemacht.
                    Vielleicht sind sie der nächste.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i>
                <h4>Fotografie</h4>
                <p>Ich fotografiere schon seit über 5 Jahren, aber erst seit 2-3 Jahren beschäftige ich mich intensiv damit.
                    Ich liebe es einfach kreativ zu sein und Dinge ins rechte Licht zu rücken.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-5x"></i>
                <h4>Grafik Design</h4>
                <p>Von Visitenkarten bis Logos habe ich alles schon gemacht und in diesem Bereich setzt einem nur die Kreativität Grenzen.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="information" class="pad-section">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</section>
<section id="portfolio" class="pad-section" >
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center">Portfolio</h2> <hr>
</div>
    <div class="container-slide">
        <div class="row img-gallary">
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-0">
                <a href="Img/IMG_0063.jpg" data-lightbox="ptfo"><img src="Img/IMG_0063.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-0">
                <a href="Img/IMG_1466.jpg" data-lightbox="ptfo"><img src="Img/IMG_1466.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-0">
                <a href="Img/IMG_1112.jpg" data-lightbox="ptfo"><img src="Img/IMG_1112.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-0">
                <a href="Img/IMG_1016.jpg" data-lightbox="ptfo"><img src="Img/IMG_1016.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-0">
                <a href="Img/IMG_0135.jpg" data-lightbox="ptfo"><img src="Img/IMG_0135.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-0">
                <a href="Img/IMG_0976.jpg" data-lightbox="ptfo"><img src="Img/IMG_0976.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-0">
                <a href="Img/IMG_0725.jpg" data-lightbox="ptfo"><img src="Img/IMG_0725.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-0">
                <a href="Img/IMG_2034.jpg" data-lightbox="ptfo"><img src="Img/IMG_2034.jpg"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
<section class="contact">
    <section id="contact" >
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Vor-Nachname" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nachricht</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input id="submit" class="submit-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Senden" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</section>
<footer>
    <hr />
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-right">Copyright &copy; Matthias Skopek 2016 </p>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[And this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJeTC.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be helpful for us if you could share a compilable and copy pasteable code

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code or create a JSfiddle so that the community can assist. Without relevant information, the question is useless as no one will be able to help fix the issue. Posting a question without all of the data and asking for help is like asking someone to cut your steak and only handing them a spoon.

Comment: You have duplicated `meta viewport` and scripts loading.

Comment: also `.container container-portfolio{` is missing `.` for `.container-portfolio`

Comment: You have wrongly mixed selfclosing tags too (have `/>` and `>` in head section). Fix your markup, it might magically help.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need this twice (in head section and before )

```html
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips but nothing changed.